# Error de consulta GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, graphql

Hola tengo el siguiente error por consola:

> message: "Cannot query field "totalClientes" on type "Query". Did you mean "getClientes" or "getCliente"?"

no se que pueda estar haciendo mal, ya revise mi resolver  esta correcto, asi como mi schema incluso al hacer la consulta en el playground funciona correctamente, pero a la hora de mandarla a llamar en mis queries para usar en react dice esto:

> Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code
>   400

**aquí esta mi resolver**

```
totalClientes: (root) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, object) => {
                Clientes.countDocuments({}, (error, count) => {
                    if(error) rejects(error)
                    else resolve(count)
                })
            });
        },
```

**Mi type query en el schema**

```
type Query {
        getClientes(limite: Int, offset: Int) : [Cliente]
        getCliente(id: ID): Cliente
        totalClientes: String
    }
```

**aqui usando la querie con gql para usarla con apollo**

```
export const CLIENTES_QUERY = gql `{

    getClientes {
    id
    nombre
    apellido
    empresa
  }
  totalClientes

}`;
```

Lo unico que hace la consulta es retornar un String de la cantidad de documentos en mi case de datos de mongodb, cuando quito la función **totalClientes** me muestra perfectamente los registro pero al ponerla es cuando inician estos problemas, lo curioso es que en mi playground de apollo hago la misma consulta y me arroja el resultado deseado. Adjunto la foto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    import React, { Component }from 'react';
import { Query, Mutation } from 'react-apollo';
import { CLIENTES_QUERY } from '../queries';
import { ELIMINAR_CLIENTE }  from '../mutations';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Paginador from './Paginador';

class Clientes extends Component{

    state = {
        pagindor: {
            offset: 0,
            actual: 1
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Query query={CLIENTES_QUERY} pollInterval={1000}>
                {({ loading, error, data, startPolling, stopPolling }) => {
                    if(loading) return "Cargando...";
                    if(error) return `Error: ${error.message}`;


                    return (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <h2 className="text-center">Listado Clientes</h2>

                            <ul className="list-group mt-4">
                                {data.getClientes.map(item => {
                                    const {id} = item;

                                    return(
                                        <li key={item.id} className="list-group-item">
                                            <div className="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                                <div className="col-md-8 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                                    {item.nombre} {item.apellido} - {item.empresa}
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-end">
                                                    <Mutation mutation={ELIMINAR_CLIENTE}>
                                                        {eliminarCliente => (
                                                            <button 
                                                                type="button" 
                                                                className="btn btn-danger d-block d-md-inline-block mr-2"
                                                                onClick={ () => {
                                                                    if(window.confirm('Seguro que deseas elimnar este cliente?')){
                                                                        eliminarCliente({
                                                                            variables: {id}
                                                                        })
                                                                    }
                                                                }}
                                                            >
                                                            &times; Eliminar
                                                            </button>
                                                        )}
                                                    </Mutation>
                                                    <Link to={`/cliente/editar/${item.id}`} className="btn btn-success d-block d-md-inline-block">
                                                        Editar cliente
                                                    </Link>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    )
                                })}
                            </ul>
                            <Paginador
                            actual={this.state.pagindor.actual}
                            />
                        </React.Fragment>
                    );
                }}

            </Query>
        )

    }
}


export default Clientes;
```

Comment: Pues poner el código del component de como lo estas haciendo en React

Comment: @afr ya acabo de agregar el component donde hago el render de la información, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que ya entendí tu problema, por lo que veo Apollo entiende que estas llamando una sola `query`. Lo que que se me ocurre es que podrías hacer Fragments de Apollo-Client y llamar tus dos queries `getClientes  totalClientes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una disculpa, fue un error enorme mío cambie el puerto en la configuración del servidor de express, pero no en la configuración de reactjs, corregí el puerto y todo listo! mil gracias de todos modos.